# How to convert data[i].int into a vairable

Tags: c++

So I'm kind of new to c++ and I'm currently working with strings. and I want to input some amount and compare them to each other, but since i have them in data type in arrays it wont let me do the substrcution and I don't understand why

```
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    cout << "Name"<< endl;
    cin >> data[i].name;
    cin >> data[i].all;
    cin >> data[i].con;
}

exceed = data[i].con-data[i].all;
while (exceed > maxvalue){
maxindex = -1;
maxvalue = exceed;

if (maxvalue > 0){
    cout << data[i].name;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and include all errors you get. Otherwise it's impossible to give a helpful answer

Comment: im getting the error: name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping. the thing is the rest of the code is fine i jsut want to input the 2 integers (the 'all' and the 'con' are ints) and want to work with them but i get confused on how to..

Comment: The only `i` in this code snippet is part of the `for` loop, so you'd need to define it outside of that if you want to use it outside of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what type or struct or class you're using for your `data` member, or what error you're encountering it's hard to tell you what exactly is going on. You are also referencing `i` outside of your for loop so that may be your issue.

I've recreated a short program that seems to be doing what you're going for with a simple struct. Because the struct defines `con` and `all` as int types, they are converted on input, and `i` is no longer referenced outside of the for loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct dataType {
    std::string name;
    int all;
    int con;
};

int main() {
    int N = 2;
    int maxValue = 3;
    dataType data[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Name" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> data[i].name;
        std::cin >> data[i].all;
        std::cin >> data[i].con;

        int exceed = data[i].con - data[i].all;
        if (exceed > maxValue) {
            std::cout << data[i].name << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using a struct or something where `con` and `all` are strings, there is a method in std::string `stoi` that can convert string types to int. Below is a short example.

```
int x;
std::string test = "4";
x = std::stoi(test);
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

Note that an invalid argument in stoi throws an exception, but as a beginner you probably haven't learned about exception handling yet (but you should once you get the hang of things).

Hope that helps, cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much, so basically i needed the std before and it did work this time

Comment: You're welcome! In the future, mention which error you're receiving on compilation or while running so it's easier to track down the issue. Good luck with the rest of the project!